# File & Path separator on Cygwin (Java)

Tags: java, cygwin

I am running `Cygwin` on `Windows 8`. A basic Java program:

```
public class FileSeparatorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("File separator = " + File.separator);
        System.out.println("OS = " + System.getProperty("os.name"));
        System.out.println("Path separator = " + File.pathSeparator);
    }
}
```

results in the following output:

```
File separator = \  
OS = Windows 8  
Path separator = ;
```

However, on `Cygwin`the file and path separators are the same as on Unix (/ and : respectively). I understand that Java is picking up these values from the underlying OS (Windows in this case), where is the translation taking place? Where does Cygwin translate all the Unix-y things we type and convert it into Windows specific separators?

Comment: Cygwin emulates unix environment including bash, utilities, file paths etc., so your result seems reasonable.

Comment: @Everv0id: That I get. Where does the 'translation' take place between Cygwin and windows?